# Unity 2d: Sprite change for selected ball prefab works only when prefab is selected from the project files and visible in the inspector. (See Video)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a shop/store in my unity game, but I am not able to select different balls. The flow is working when I have selected the ball prefab in the project panel and the prefab is visible in the inspector.

Please Check this 40 seconds video to understand the issue
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YtNitI_z7vrMQpNRKyiaJ7wuvqmgY7SN/view?usp=sharing)

More information

In this flow there are 2 scripts :

ShopManager Script, it has a method **SelectItem** in this method, I am setting the sprite

```
public void SelectItem(int buttonId)
{       
        ... existing code ....

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LastSelectedBall", previouslySelectedButton);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LastSelectedPower", ballsSO[0].balls[buttonId].powerPercentage);
        
        // Save sprite information (consider converting Sprite to a string or using sprite index/id)
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastSelectedSprite", ballsSO[0].balls[buttonId].ballSprite.name);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        ballController.SetPower(ballsSO[0].balls[buttonId].powerPercentage);
        ballController.SetSprite(ballsSO[0].balls[buttonId].ballSprite);

    }
}
```

BallController Script, here is the implementation of SetPower and SetSprite methods

```
public void SetPower(int power)
{
    maxPower = power;
}

public void SetSprite(Sprite ballSprite)
{
    ballSpriteRenderer.sprite = ballSprite;
}
```

Please Check this 40 seconds video to understand the issue
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YtNitI_z7vrMQpNRKyiaJ7wuvqmgY7SN/view?usp=sharing)

Why is that happening? and how to fix this, so that it will work correctly. If more info required, let me know.

Comment: Where did your ballController script reference to? Prefab object or GameObject created from prefab?

Comment: @AustinYang Prefab object

Comment: put in debug messages to see whats going on

Comment: @BugFinder I have tried that, but not able to find anything.

Comment: then it suggests not enough messages were put in to debug it

Comment: I think unity only update preive image when `OnInspectorGUI` is triggered, i.e., when you select the prefab and make it appear in Inspector. But why did you want to change the sprite of a prefab instead of initating a new gameObject and change sprite for it?